# Why the Emulator wont start or show in SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I am facing a problem with my Android studio SDK manager. I have created several images using the AVD but when I run the application, Android studio cannot find the images.[image]

After going through the setup, it completes successfully
[image]

but when I hit the run button for it to launch the emulator, the process repeats all over again
[image]

Comment: Have you created actual emulator?

Comment: Yes i have. But the IDE does not detect it.

Comment: Is it running in the background but android studio cant detect it when you try to launch your app or it isnt running at all?

Comment: The emulator is not even running. There is nothing in the background I have checked from my task manager

Comment: its not that it cant find your emulator,your emulator just isnt running,the heading on your question is misleading

Comment: Try and delete the system image and reinstall,it might have been corrupt

Comment: Tried. Still not working

Comment: You need to ask a new question on why your emulator wont start,as far as android sdk is concerned I believe iv answered that